# Services on Azure only starts after restart

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, windows-server-2016

We have a VM on Azure where some Windows services only starts when the VM is restarted but not if it is stopped and then started. When trying to start the service manually after the server has been stopped and started gives the following error:

```
Windows could not start the ... service on Local Computer. 

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Where ... is the name of the service.

What is the difference between "Restart" and "Stop then Start" an Azure VM?

Answer (score 0):

When you restart a VM in Azure, the OS is rebooted and the hardware the OS is being provisioned on remains the same throughout restarts. So for example, if your VM is hosted on Cluster 1, Node 1 and you perform a restart, once the OS comes back up you will still be located on Cluster 1, node 1.

However, if you stop and start your VM that will release the resources associated with your VM within the data center. So again, if you are on Cluster 1, Node 1 and you stop your VM, your machine is now no longer located on that cluster and that node. When you start the VM back up again, Azure will search the datacenter for the correct cluster that can host the specific size and requirements your VM requires and allocate new resources.

Restart = Remain on same hardware | 
Stop = Release resources

If you are having issues with services not starting, it would likely be related to their startup method. Check the windows services by logging into the VM and change them to automatic or delayed instead of manual.